# Inquiries about handling request limits for generating images concurrently

Tags: multiprocessing, openai-api

I'm planning to subscribe to OpenAI's ChatGPT tier 1 or the Basic plan of the Leonardo API for an image generation application. Both options have a limit of 5 concurrent requests. Does anyone have experience in handling multiple user requests simultaneously?

[image: Open AI API plan tier 1]

[image: Leonardo API plan basic]

I would like to know how to handle the situation so that the sixth user onwards doesn't experience failures when generating images concurrently. Also, which option would you recommend, OpenAI or Leonardo AI?

Comment: Could you perhaps store the 5 current users in a database table, and anyone else that tries to join ends up in the que table, and as the ques free up, one is moved from the que to the active 5?  This would allow you to just need 5 slots, but you have to build the que system.